# Case expression with multiple true conditions

Tags: sql, oracle, case

Why is my case expression returning multiple rows. I thought the case expression captures the first true condition then stops.

I have the below and it returns two rows. Why is this and what can I add in my case expression to stop when the first true condition is met?

```
 with
sample_data1(ID, START_DATE,ASSIGNMENT_DATE ) as (
select 1, to_date('11/07/2018', 'mm/dd/yyyy'),to_date('10/01/2018', 'mm/dd/yyyy') from dual UNION ALL
select 1, to_date('11/07/2018', 'mm/dd/yyyy'),to_date('11/08/2018', 'mm/dd/yyyy') from dual

)


SELECT 
ID,
START_dATE,
CASE
WHEN ASSIGNMENT_DATE < START_DATE THEN START_DATE
WHEN ASSIGNMENT_DATE > START_DATE  THEN ASSIGNMENT_DATE
END FIRST_DATE
FROM sample_data1
```

I would expect the below table output:

```
ID  START_DATE  FIRST_DATE   ASSIGNMENT_DATE
1    11/7/18      11/7/18        10/1/18
1    11/7/18      11/7/18        11/8/18
```

Comment: It's true that the case captures the first true condition, but it does that *for each row* not filtered out from the query. I think what you want here is to group by ID and START_DATE, and use a MIN on the result of your CASE statement.

Comment: Your results make no sense (to me) given your sample data.